# Running method in its own datasource transaction when called from other service which is using datasoure-2 transaction

Tags: transactions, spring-transactions

I have a scenario where 2 different datasources are used.

datasource 1 service class (which is transaction enabled) calling a datasource 2 service class method (which is transaction enabled but with datasource2)

Code is given below. My Requirement is how to run persistOneByOne() in a separate transaction when we call in this hierarchy.If exeption occurs dont persist that record but since its in for loop proceed to processing other records.
How do i achieve this behaviour.

// Service class 2 uses a datasource-1 which is transacation enabled by aop

```
public class DataSource1ServiceClass1{
    DataSource2OtherServiceClass service2;

     public void processData(){
           service2.prepareAndPeristData();
      }
    }
```

// Service class 2 uses a different data source called datasource-2 which is also transaction enabled by aop

```
public class DataSource2OtherServiceClass{

     public void prepareAndPeristData(){
         try{
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
              {
            // pre processing before persisting a single record
            persistOneByOne();
              }
            }catch (Exception e){
               log.error("Error occurred.. so didn't persist record as expected"};
            }


     public void persistOneByOne()
       {
          dao.persist();
       } 
}
```

Configuration xml file:

```
<bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="allServices"
            expression="execution(* .service.impl.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allServices" />
    </aop:config>


<bean id="txManager2"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="otherDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice2" transaction-manager="txManager2">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="allOtherServices"
            expression="execution(* .service2.impl.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice2" pointcut-ref="allOtherServices" />
    </aop:config>
```

How do i achieve persistOneByOne() to be run in its own transaction .if exception occurs roll back for that single row.

Answer (score 0):

I think your scenario fits the savepoints based database interaction. Spring supports it with `NESTED` propagation.

If you apply the  Nested propagation advice to  the `persistOneByOne()` method in your code; it would create a savepoint every time that method is executed and will roll back to the last savepoint if an excpetion occurs. And then continue to next.

Technically, you can do it by applying `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation advice to your method as well but it would open up a new transaction every time it is called.It is considered a bad practice as it will thrash your database in case of high volume transactions.

You can look at this for more details: http://www.marcobehler.com/make-it-so-java-db-connections-and-transactions-html/spring-transactional-propagation-propagation-nested.html

Also, you can remove the transactional advice from your congiuration for `txManager2`and then annotate the method/class with `@Transactional` annotation instead with transactionManager. Doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

You will need to add this in your configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

With this, you class would look something like this:

```
public class DataSource2OtherServiceClass{

     @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class}, propagation=PROPAGATION.REQUIRES_NEW, transactionManager="txManager2")
     public void prepareAndPeristData(){
         try{
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
              {
            // pre processing before persisting a single record
            persistOneByOne();
              }
            }catch (Exception e){
               log.error("Error occurred.. so didn't persist record as expected"};
            }

     @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class}, propagation=PROPAGATION.NESTED, transactionManager="txManager2")
     public void persistOneByOne()
       {
          dao.persist();
       } 
}
```